# Is there a way to open a directory from JavaScript and use it as a (persistent) source for assets like images?

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

I would like to store images and configuration data on a device in a persistent manor.

Previously I have seen LocalStorage and IndexedDB being inexplicably wiped so I don't trust them as persistent, perhaps more like long term temporary storage.

I also can't really store images there without converting the images to base64 and storing them as text, which is a little cumbersome.

I would like the user to be prompted that my web app would like to access the filesystem so they are cognizant of that, but I would not like to have access to everything and I would like the prompt to appear once on first launch.

I am reading through the FileSystem API and it looks like there might be a solution there but I haven't found it yet.

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Webkit browsers have something you could use, but it's not standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem

Comment: Maybe it's a better idea to store actual data like that on a server and associate it with some kind of user ids or even accounts? I know that's a useless suggestion if you are constrained to client-side but maybe you have other options.

Comment: In this case I am trying to write an installable web app that operates entirely on the client-side. The only server is the S3 bucket hosting the web app.